# Error when using Double.parseDouble from text field

Tags: java, parsing, actionlistener

i have been trying to take an input from a text field and put it in a Double variable. but when ever i try to use `Double.parseDouble(textTF.getText())` i get errors, i tested using scanner it worked fine

```
private class NumRTFHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String romanN = "";
        String dec = numDTF.getText();
        Double decimal = Double.parseDouble(dec);
    }
}
```

i guessed it might be the Action listener but im not sure how to deal with it. `Double.parseDouble()` didn't work neither with a textField nor with a string.

please Help.

these are the errors.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at RomanNumeralConvertert$NumRTFHandler.actionPerformed(RomanNumeralConvertert.java:40)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I declared numDTF at the top

```
JTextField numDTF;
```

and it gets the input from the user.

Edit:

here is the whole code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RomanNumeralConvertert extends JFrame {

  private static final int HEIGHT = 60;  
  private static final int WIDTH = 600;

  private JLabel numRL, numDL;  
  private JTextField numRTF, numDTF;
  private NumRTFHandler nrh;
  private NumDTFHandler ndh;

  public RomanNumeralConvertert() {
    setTitle("Roman Numeral to Decimal Converter");                  
    numRL = new JLabel("Decimal Value: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    numDL = new JLabel("Roman Numeral: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    numRTF = new JTextField(10);
    numDTF = new JTextField(10);
    nrh = new NumRTFHandler();
    ndh = new NumDTFHandler();
    numRTF.addActionListener(nrh);
    numDTF.addActionListener(ndh);

    Container pane = getContentPane();            
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    pane.add(numDL); pane.add(numDTF);
    pane.add(numRL); pane.add(numRTF);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);                     
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  private class NumRTFHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String romanN = "";
      String dec = numDTF.getText();
      Double decimal = Double.parseDouble(dec);
      //converting to Roman Numerals 
      while(decimal >= 1000){
        romanN += "M";
        decimal -= 1000.0;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 900){
        romanN += "CM";
        decimal -= 900;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 500){
        romanN += "D";
        decimal -= 500;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 400){
        romanN += "CD";
        decimal -= 400;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 100){
        romanN += "C";
        decimal -= 100;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 90){
        romanN += "XC";
        decimal -= 90;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 50){
        romanN += "L";
        decimal -= 50;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 40){
        romanN += "XL";
        decimal -= 40;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 10){
        romanN += "X";
        decimal -= 10;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 9){
        romanN += "IX";
        decimal -= 9;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 5){
        romanN += "V";
        decimal -= 5;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 4){
        romanN += "IV";
        decimal -= 4;  
      }
      while(decimal >= 1){
        romanN += "I";
        decimal -= 1;  
      }
      numRTF.setText(romanN);
    }
  }

  private class NumDTFHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String romanN = numDTF.getText();
      double decimal = 0;
      romanN.toUpperCase();
      int i=0;
      while(i <= romanN.length()){
        char char1 = romanN.charAt(i);
        i++;
        char char2 ='i';
        if(i < romanN.length()){
          char2 = romanN.charAt(i+1);
          i++;
        }
        if( char1 == ('M')){
          decimal +=1000;
        }
        if( char1 == ('D')){
          decimal +=500;
        }
        if( char1 ==('C')){
          if( char2 == ('M')){
            decimal +=900;
          }
          if( char1 == ('D')){
            decimal +=400;
          }
        }else{
          decimal += 100;
        }
        if( char1 == ('L')){
          decimal +=50;
        }
        if( char1 == ('X')){
          if( char2 == ('C')){
            decimal +=90;
          }
          if( char1 == ('L')){
            decimal +=40;
          }
        }else{
          decimal += 10;
        }
        if( char1 == ('V')){
          decimal +=5;
        }
        if( char1 == ('1')){
          if( char2 == ('X')){
            decimal +=9;
          }
          if( char1 == ('V')){
            decimal +=4;
          }
       }else{
          decimal += 1;
       }
      }
      numDTF.setText("" + decimal);

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RomanNumeralConvertert gui = new RomanNumeralConvertert();
  }
  // End of the Code
}
```

I couldn't figure it out, i checked the logic and no problems with that.

edit:

i have solved the problem that caused the empty string. there were some text fields names 
switched together, just needed to change the names, it is working now, and the logic here had few problem but solved that too.

Comment: What errors you get? Post stacktrace.

Comment: "i get errors": Can you please specify, which error? Stack trace is really helpful.

Comment: textTF.getText() get proper double + what error u face

Comment: When asking a question tell us the exact error you are getting, there is a better change we can help you if we know what to look for. BTW, where did you declare `numDTF` ?

Comment: check the content of "dec" there must be something wrong with the value in dec.

Comment: What is the input into the `numDTF` textField when the error occurs? Without that, we cannot see why there is a parsing error.

Comment: The error says that the string is empty. Does the `numDTF` field have any content? You should check the `dec` String via `isEmpty()` before attempting to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `empty string` error, and from the code you posted I would guess that calling the `getText()` method is not able to return anything because `numDTF` does not have a value.

Comment: the text field `numDTF` should get the input from the user, i tested it and every time i type a number and hit enter it give this error

Comment: should get or DOES get. - add the rest of your code